# NuGet and Portable Class Libraries - Package doesn't target any framework

Tags: nuget, portable-class-library

I have been using NuGet to manage my internally created assemblies for a few months, and it's working very well. I recently 'discovered' portable class libraries, which has also been great - until it's time to install the packages.

Say I have a PCL that targets .NET 4.5, SL5 and .NET for Windows Store Apps. I run `nuget spec` to create the .nuspec file, edit the values, package it up, and add the .nupkg to our internal feed. If I open the .nupkg file in the Package Explorer, I see one content folder under lib called portable-win+net45+sl50.

When I try to install the package from any compatible project in another solution, I get the following message:

"'Project.PCL' could not be installed because it is not compatible with any project in the solution. The package doesn't target any framework."

If I manually create the .nupkg in the Package Explorer, updating the version number, adding a lib folder for each targeted framework (not a portable folder) and added the Project.PCL.dll to each folder, I can add the package to the compatible projects in the solution. But to do this process every time I want to update a PCl is somewhat tedious (I had been creating a little .cmd file in the project root folder to quickly package and deploy).

Do other people have this problem? How can I package PCL's in the same way as other types of projects?

Note - I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate and NuGet 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like maybe `nuget spec` doesn't work for Portable Class Libraries - that's worth starting a thread or filing an issue on the [NuGet site](http://nuget.codeplex.com/).

However, you can also create a .nuspec file from NuGet Package Explorer.  Just create the package as you already did, but then choose "Save Metadata As..." to save it as a .nuspec.  Afterwards you may need to edit the source paths in the nuspec file manually, but you should be able to automate the creation of the package.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I hadn't realised that I could manually add files to the nuspec.

Answer (score 1):

For me nuget spec and nuget pack worked fine with a portable project while creating the package and installing it on a compatible project.
Do you want to check if you have the latest nuget.exe (2.2), it can be downloaded from http://nuget.org/nuget.exe or can be updated by running nuget update -self

Comment: I checked that, I do have NuGet 2.2. What process do you use to create the package?

Comment: from the command prompt in the project folder, I do nuget spec and then run nuget pack. Can you share your nuget package somewhere that you created from the command line and I can give it a try?

Comment: I created a package that targets .NET 4.5, SL5 and Windows Store apps, ran nuget spec and nuget pack. I cannot install that package through Visual Studio into any projects. Here is the package on [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=76DC2E460C575501!115&authkey=!AO6RVZrj_Y3Ym0o)

Comment: thanks for sharing the package, I was able to install it  on a portable class library targeting .net windows store app + .net 4.5 +  SL5

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with some part of my installation or something. Anyway, thanks for your help.